# How to simplify this summation involving floor functions?

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have obtained the following summation:
$$S_{n} = \sum_{\substack{i \ge 0 \\ 2^{i+2} + i \le n}} \left\lfloor \frac{n - i}{2^{i + 1}} \right\rfloor$$

Can this be further simplified?

---

***Background:*** This summation arises in a solution to the following problem on algorithm analysis (from Exercise 18.2-4 of Chapter 18 on B-Trees; Book: Introduction to Algorithms (known as CLRS) 3rd):

> Suppose that the keys $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ (in increasing order) are inserted into an empty B-tree with minimum degree 2. How many nodes does the final B-tree have?

Comment: why is an inequality sitting on top of the summation symbol

Comment: The summation might be clearer if you wrote it like this: $$\sum_{\substack{i \geq 0\\2^{i+2} + i \le n}}$$

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your weird sum. $$S_{17}=\left\lfloor\frac{17}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{16}4\right\rfloor=8+4=12$$ Did I get that right?

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. I have modified it as you suggested.

Comment: @bof Yes. Sorry for the messy notations. I have modified it.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry for the messy notations. I have modified it.

Comment: In other words you sum over all terms where $\left\lfloor\frac{n-i}{2^{i+1}}\right\rfloor\ge2$. It's the same as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n-i}{2^{i+1}}\right\rfloor$ except that if there is a term equal to $1$ you delete it. Why don't you tell us the motivation for this funny expression?

Comment: @bof It is from a solution to a problem on algorithm analysis. I have added a paragraph for the background. The solution is quite non-trivial, so I did not include it (for now). (Perhaps there is a nice solution which avoids such a summation.)

Comment: Emperically, $n-S_n$ is nonnegative but pretty small, on the order of $\ln n$ ... there's a funny dependence on the fractional part of $\ln n$ as well.